How to find IRQ numbers on Pi5?
I want to write a custom PWM kernel module, I want to write a handler which is called when the PWM interrupt is triggered.
What IRQ number do I use when attaching the handler?

Sometimes, the IRQ numbers are defined in header files specific to your platform or development environment. Check if there are any header files provided with your development kit or platform that define the IRQ numbers for the PWM controller.

By the way, have you tried asking this question to the Raspberry Pi forum?
